# Simple Java Server to listen to a client and redirect[302] to some other site

Tags: java, tomcat

Before you close this question as duplicate, I tried many thing found here and nothing worked. A bit new to server coding in Java.
What I need is a simple server which should listen to a port to get some data. 
I need to work on the data, and save it somewhere(that I can handle) and then redirect to some other website.
I started with simple server using Sockets then people started suggesting tomcat and all. Tried many things, got lost in set ups, and configurations... and at last coming back here to ask (thinking why didn't I do this earlier).

Please let me know if you need more info.

EDIT:
What I am doing - 
     Using Serversocket with thread to handle multiple requests. Done
     Reading client request BufferedReader and working on it. Done
     Need to do a post request after processing. To do. :(
     Need to respond to client with 302 redirect. Not sure if working -

```
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); 
out.println("HTTP/1.0 302 Found"); 
out.println("Location: http://www.xyz.co"); 
out.flush(); 
out.close(); 
connection.close();
```

Comment: Please provide steps you have already taken to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, seems to be working a bit now still having other issues.
What I did - Using ServerSocket with threads to read data and process it as per required, need to store.. then send response 302. I am not sure if I am sending response correctly. Any way to verify?

Comment: Solved it. I myself can't close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to send a redirect, this tells me you want to use HTTP Protocol. If you want to support a few different http commands then you are better off with an HTTP server like Tomcat (that's what I would use, but then I know Tomcat quite well).

Otherwise, if you are happy just to implement the parts of HTTP that you need, then writing a simple server could do what you want (and nothing else). However, you will have to think about a few things, like how many connections are you expecting at one time? (More than 1? You need to open each connection in a new thread). When you send the redirect you will have to build up an HTTP response. This question might help you:

[How can I send an HTTP Response using only standard network libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696986/how-can-i-send-an-http-response-using-only-standard-network-libraries)